What functions does google play billling call when in "test subscription renewal" after the first renewal?
Google suggests to test "your google play billing". I do have a product with weekly
and monthly renewal. I want to test the renewal. I did find that test subscriptions for 1 week are renewed after 5 minutes.  This is great.
But i didnt find any information on what really is done - will a running instance
of "BillingClient"  be called automatically by Google, so that it calls listeners in my app ?  Or will i have to rely on polling ?
This isnt documented anywhere. So if someone knows -please share your expertise.
My code is tested for the "regular" case, i.e. first order of a product.
To allow use of my app when internet is down i am prepared as well, i do #
store products timestamps - i found that timestamps in PurchasesResponseListener()
are indeed the precise timestamps when the user bought the product the first name.
As of now i am missing 2 informations/ confirmations:
a) do i get the info  via polling or  via listener ?
b) if a product is renewed -will the timestamp be the time of the original (first) purchase, or will it be begin of the new period ? I would prefer the later, but i dont know ...

Ok, so i did test this in the debugger now.
Renewals of subscriptions do get the original time stamp.
boolean isRenewing =  pu.isAutoRenewing();
long purchasetime = Purchase.getPurchaseState(); 

So purchasetime is -not- increased with each renewal of a subscription.
isAutoRenewing is true, as expected.
With respect to polling versus listeners : i do simply call BillingClient in onCreate of the application and
again each time my order dialog is shown on the screen.
Worstcase is that the user had the order dialog opened
a minute before the subscription period renews, he/she would then not get the update correctly. Had to wait for the next start of the app or next open of the dialog.
